# Unable to add new notifications in WordPress Admin using "admin-notices" hook

Tags: php, wordpress, api, plugins, hook

I have been trying to add a new Admin Notice whenever I receive a certain response from API. Below is the code I am using. I have also added an error log statement for debugging. It seems that the error log statement gets logged correctly. But still, no notice is being shown in the WordPress Admin dash :/. Any assistance would be really appreciated. FS: This block is under a function.

```
if ( isset( $response_body['error'] ) && $response_body['error']['message'] === 'You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.' ) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'display_admin_notice' );
        function display_admin_notice() {
            ?>
            <div class="notice notice-error">
                <p><?php _e( 'API LIMIT reached. Please re-check your API credit for the plugin to work properly.', 'my-plugin-textdomain' ); ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        error_log('API LIMIT EXCEEDED');
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: I tried to use a logic, and check if it's getting hooked correctly. I used the below code. It appears that it's getting hooked correctly, but nothing is getting displayed in the Admin dash.

```
if ( !add_action( 'admin_notices', 'display_admin_notice', 10, 1 ) ) {
    error_log( 'Hooked the notification correctly.' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I started by an answer to ask you if you were still blocked because I was in the same situation and my answer has been deleted :)

Then I continued to search for a fix and here is the solution for me: I was using

```
add_action('admin_notices', 'quota_exceeded');
```

Which was doing nothing... but with this adaptation it's working fine!

```
add_action('admin_notices', array($this, 'quota_exceeded'));
```

I hope it will solve your issue ;-)